# prevent app dragging but permit scroll of inner div elements in ios

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, cordova

I have a web app that I am adapting to iOS5 using Phonegap.  Everything works except for one issue:

My inner `<div>`s, which are set to scroll if overflowed and scroll perfectly if overflowed in Chrome do not scroll at all on the iPad.

--I have disabled app dragging by disabling touchmove;
--i have implemented (perhaps incorrectly?) the -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch CSS property that is, apparently, new to iOS5 like so:

overflow: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;

Nothing seems to work.

If I comment out the javascript (from Phonegap) that disables app dragging (ie. touchmove), then the scrolling works but it drags and scrolls the entire app.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a hack, but you can do some checking to see if you're touching the `div` or not, and depending on that, you prevent scrolling like so:

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e){
    if(document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY) !== document.getElementById('yourdiv'){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.elementFromPoint)

Comment: Thanks very much Amaan.  Seems like a hack is involved no matter what, so I appreciate the code.

Comment: Hi Amaan, finally got a chance to try the code but can't get it to work on iOS5, despite the fact that it logically makes perfect sense.  If you have any other thoughts I would appreciate it.

Comment: @robertsmith Could you post the entire code then? On http://JSFiddle.net if it's not too long, or on http://PasteBin.com

Comment: Thanks Amaan.  I got it to work in a slightly different way, by using a named function to disable touchmove, and then referring to it in each main div I needed to.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Oh, well, that's a good solution too. You may want to try `e.touches[0].pageX` instead of `e.pageX` and the same for `e.pageY`. May be the reason this didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I was able to prevent dragging of the main app/page by using the following code:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('idMyDiv');

myDiv.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```