# Disable dragging only on "body" element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

On iOS, I want to disable scrolling on the `<body>` element only, not elements within the `<body>` element. The following code will disable dragging on the `<body>` element, but also prevents dragging on child divs:

```
$("body").bind("touchstart", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Is there anyway for this to just affect the parent div, not the child div's within the parent (`<body>`)? I thought maybe `$("#yourdiv").parent()` would work, but no luck.

**EDIT**: This link, while it addresses the same issue, did not solve my problem: [prevent app dragging but permit scroll of inner div elements in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292326/prevent-app-dragging-but-permit-scroll-of-inner-div-elements-in-ios)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("body").bind("touchstart", function(e) {
    if(e.target.nodeName === "BODY"){
       e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

You could check the `target` of the event - not 100% sure how this goes on iOS, but I'd assume it should be fine.

Another possibility would be to stop the event from propagating in the first place.

```
$("*:not(body)").bind('touchstart', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

But this is just a thought, and I'm also not entirely sure it would work.

Comment: Works perfectly. The only problem is that if you scroll the scroll bar all the way to the top in the scrolling div, then try to drag while it's momentum is resetting back to rest, it will drag the page. This is obviously pretty specific, so I doubt there's a workaround.

Comment: To add on to my previous comment, this also happens when you try dragging up within the scrollable div when it's already up as far as it can go, it will scroll the body instead.

Comment: You could stop event propagation also - from the elements you still want to scroll...

Comment: Could you elaborate on that a little more?

Answer (score 3):

You could also compare `this` with `e.target`.

```
$("body").bind("touchstart", function(e) {
    if (this === e.target) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how different it would be on iOS (haven't tested it there yet), but here's how I solved the problem on Android.

[JSBIN DEMO](http://bit.ly/1pHtqBx)

The solution involves a few things:

1. Disabling default Body `touchmove` event
2. Preventing `touchmove` event from bubbling to body on targets you want `touchmove` to work on
3. Forcing overscroll on permitted targets to bubble to body and get negated